# How to make Spring Data Rest work with reference to the same entity type?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have this entity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private Employee manager;
}
```

With corresponding repository:

```java
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    // ..
}
```

When I make a `GET` request to **find employee by `id`** I get this result:

```json
{
   "firstName":"Steven",
   "lastName":"King",
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8081/api/employees/100"
      },
      "employee":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8081/api/employees/100"
      },
      "manager":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8081/api/employees/100/manager"
      }
   }
}
```

The `http://localhost:8081/api/employees/100/manager` just doesn't work with **`Lazy` fetching**, so how do I change it to something like: `http://localhost:8081/api/employees/99` where **99** is the `id` of Steven's manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Spring Data REST Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.customizing-json-output), you can define a bean of type `RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<T>>`, which are automatically picked up by Spring Data REST when serializing an entity of type `T`.

You can build an `EntityModel` there by yourself.

```java
@Component
public class EmployeeModelProcessor implements RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<Employee>> {

    private final RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks;

    public EmployeeModelProcessor(RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks) {
        this.entityLinks = entityLinks;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityModel<Employee> process(EntityModel<Employee> employeeModel) {

        Employee employee = employeeModel.getContent();

        EntityModel<Employee> newEmployeeModel = EntityModel.of(employee);
        newEmployeeModel.add(employeeModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF));
        newEmployeeModel.add(employeeModel.getRequiredLink("employee"));

        if (null != employee.getManager()) {
            newEmployeeModel.add(entityLinks.linkToItemResource(Employee.class, employee.getManager().getId()).withRel("manager"));
        }

        return newEmployeeModel;
    }

}
```

You can find documentation about `RepositoryEntityLinks` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#integration).

Then the response JSON should become

```json
{
   "firstName":"Steven",
   "lastName":"King",
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8081/api/employees/100"
      },
      "employee":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8081/api/employees/100"
      },
      "manager":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8081/api/employees/99"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have this result

```json
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8081/api/employees/101"
},
"employee": [
{
"href": "http://localhost:8081/api/employees/101"
},
{
"href": "http://localhost:8081/api/employees/100"
}
]
}
```

Is there something with the versions of spring HATEOAS or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I update my code to set rel of manager link with code `.withRel("manager")`

Comment: thank you for getting started with this, next I gonna investigate the documentation you suggested